# Format a USB Drive that has a Pre-Installed GUI

Tags: usb-flash-drive, formatting

I have a 8GB USB flash drive with a U3 Systems GUI on it. I want to re-format it a the pre-loaded interface takes up about 100MB. Nothing major, but I want it gone. The pre-loaded interface takes forever to boot up and I like windows explorer better than it.

My question is: if I reformat the drive, thus removing the pre-installed interface, do I risk the integrity of the USB itself? Will the drive revert to a simply flash drive stick or will I have errors when running it in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be an official removal tool from Sandisk:
[launchpad removal tool](http://u3.sandisk.com/launchpadremoval.htm)

Comment: Always happens, someone adds the same answer after a better one and receives the "accept"... There should be an option to flag this.

Comment: @Jorge: Please at least be honest.  It's not the "same" answer.  If you look at your edit history, everyone can see your answer pointing to the official software was different at the time when I answered this.

Comment: You know that if you look at the link the software is excatly the same altough is in a different link. I've edited it because I know that some questioners gets fascinated just because they read "official" instead of "just a link" altough is the same software, and seems that some people knows how to get profit out of this when searching for unaccepted answers to "reanswer".

Answer (score 3):

It will be "converted" in a normal USB drive, but seems that is not as easy as formatting.

Read this forum post I found if you want more specific info: http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/243608-32-remove-smart-software-sandisk-flash-drive

And here some official software that helps removing U3:
http://u3.sandisk.com/launchpadremoval.htm